# Changing MemSQL host/node to use private IP

Tags: singlestore

The servers we use have both public and private internal IPs. When using MemSQL Ops GUI to add MemSQL host and nodes, the installation defaults to using the public IP even when provided with the private IP.

How can we have the private IP used during installation? Or how can this IP be changed after the installation?

---

Tried using `memsql-ops memsql-update-config` to update the `reported_hostname` setting which confirms a successful change and says to restart. `memsql-ops cluster-restart` doesn't show any changes though.

---

**Process that works:** 
Installing the agents through the command line through `memsql-ops agent-deploy` (after the initial ops install) then using `memsql-ops restart` on each node to restart with new interface and host bindings. Once the agent is restarted and showing the private IP, using the Ops UI to install the memsql node works fine.

Comment: Your working process here is correct; you can use the --host flag when starting MemSQL Ops on each server to ensure that each MemSQL Ops agent uses a specific host.  If you make sure to do that before you deploy any MemSQL nodes, then the MemSQL nodes will use the correct hosts as well.

Comment: FYI, we've released MemSQL Ops version 4.0.31 today. If you upgrade to that version, we've made two changes:

1. When you deploy agents through the MemSQL Ops web UI, we'll use whatever hostnames you type in at the time.  Thus, you can just type in private IPs if you want to use private IPs.
2. If you've already deployed some MemSQL nodes, you can run `memsql-ops memsql-unmonitor` to unmonitor a MemSQL node. You can then run `memsql-ops memsql-monitor -h <private IP>` in order to re-monitor the MemSQL node that's running on <private IP>; this will update its IP in MemSQL Ops.

Answer (score 0):

The IP shown in Ops is not necessarily the IPs used by MemSQL the database.

The source of truth about the addresses used in cluster is the output of the SHOW LEAVES command.

http://docs.memsql.com/latest/ref/SHOW_LEAVES/

Comment: Why is that not the truth? Why is Ops a completely separate layer that requires agents on each host? It would be better to have a single Ops install/agent that can discover and see the entire cluster from any single host address and only installs/manages memsql nodes on each host via ssh.

Comment: That's a fair question. One reason is that we sometimes need to manage clusters where SSH is not available. Security policies vary extremely widely in the field, especially enterprise. Also, it's nice to be able to collect perf data locally and aggregate it before sending to the main host. I agree that showing a different IP is not ideal, and we're looking at possible fixes.

Comment: How is the agent deployed then? Through SSH right? My question is more about why the Ops is a separate install from the memsql node? There's no point in an agent on a host without memsql. Combining the ops agents with the memsql installs would mean a single install (through whatever method) with consolidated management functions and no extra overhead or config settings, while still reporting to a single primary Ops UI - which can be its own lightweight app on any small VM.

Comment: Again, fair question. SSH is used the very first step, but not thereafter. In many environments we encounter, SSH is not available, and we use other means of getting the "seed" of Ops deployed. Ops is a separate process because it is for management and measurement of memsqld. It has a different purpose, different expectations for performance, failure modes, and release cycles from the core database engine. It is perfectly possible to run memsqld clusters without Ops; you just have to configure the nodes by hand.